# How to display custom error messages instead of the default ones?

Tags: php, yii

I'm creating a recommendation controller using PHP Yii framework, using a heuristic concept. My recommendation will only work if the user or other user with the same course have made a booking. But right now if my bookings is equal to null it is showing an error message like below:

> Error 500 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Therefore I have made a condition where I created my own message:

> We are sorry currently there are no recommendation of books at this moment

and it is working. Unfortunately, it also shows together with the error message. I just want to show only my own message. Below is my code:

```
//recommendation - use heuristic concept, more accurate result as more people same course recommendation
public function actionRecommendation() {
    $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);

    //get course mates
    $courseMates = User::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('course_id' => $user->course_id));

    $popularity = array();
    if($bookings==null){Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'We are sorry currently there are no recommendation of books at this moment'); }


    foreach ($courseMates as $courseMate) {
        //identify all bookings made by user
        $bookings = Booking::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id' => $courseMate->id));


        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
            //add hit into array as per book
            $popularity[$booking->book_id] = (isset($popularity[$booking->book_id])) ? $popularity[$booking->book_id] + 1 : 1;
        }

    }



    //sort according to popular count
    arsort($popularity, SORT_NUMERIC);

    $display = 10;
    foreach ($popularity as $bookId => $popular) {
        //if display is 0, break the foreach, only display up 10
        if ($display == 0) {

            break;
        }

        //create book object array
        $books[] = Book::model()->findByPk($bookId);

        //reduce book count
        $display--;
    }

    $this->render('recommendation',array(
        'books'=>$books,
    ));     
}()
```

How can I modify it so it displays just the custom error message?

Comment: Why not put the foreach in 'if' statement which checks if the $booking variable is not null?

Comment: still the same it kept showing my message and the error message

Comment: @AsySyah: Check if the argument is an array before passing to `foreach` (hint: use `is_array()`)

Comment: @Amal Murali: can show me an example im still in learning process

Comment: @AsySyah: Here you go: https://eval.in/120966

Comment: i've tried so many times and still kept showing the error message

Comment: @AsySyah Was this issue resolved?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...thanks alot friends for all your tips and information.

Answer (score 0):

**For Input Fields**
**In your Model**

```
array('gender','required','message'=>'Please select gender.'),
```

Or can call Function too.

```
    array('gender', 'ownFunction'),

    public function ownFunction() {        
      {
        if (empty($this->gender))
           $this->addError("gender", 'Please select gender.');
     }
}
```

Using this you can display custom error message on input fields

**For Error Page**

for Custom message in  Error Page .

**In your Controller**

```
if(Your Condition)
        {
            //Show Error form.
        throw new CHttpException(500,'We are sorry currently there are no recommendation of books at this moment.  ');
        }
        else 
        {
        /* rest of code goes Here */
        }
```

Hope this Helps You